# Привязать картинки к <input type="range> средствами js или jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Подскажите не опытному программисту как картинки (любой элемент) назначить событие с input type="range", так чтоб при изменении значения value прокручивались картинки. Просто со стрелочками получилось, а с range не могу понять как..

вот  codepen http://codepen.io/vitekiss/pen/oLZRWQ

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li.partn');
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  /*lis[i].style.position = 'relative';
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  //этот код - для удобства разработки
  span.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;left:0;top:0';
  span.innerHTML = i + 1;
  lis[i].appendChild(span);*/
}

/* конфигурация */
var width = 212; // ширина изображения
var count = 1; // количество изображений для сдвига

var carousel = document.getElementById('carousel');
var list = carousel.querySelector('div.gallery>ul');
var listElems = carousel.querySelectorAll('li.partn');

var position = 0; // текущий сдвиг влево

carousel.querySelector('.prev').onclick = function() {
  // сдвиг влево
  // последнее передвижение влево может быть не на 3, а на 2 или 1 элемент
  position = Math.min(position + width * count, 0)
  list.style.marginLeft = position + 'px';
};

carousel.querySelector('.next').onclick = function() {
  // сдвиг вправо
  // последнее передвижение вправо может быть не на 3, а на 2 или 1 элемент
  position = Math.max(position - width * count, -width * (listElems.length - count));
  list.style.marginLeft = position + 'px';
};
```

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
}
.carousel img {
  display: block;
}
.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  background: white;
  /*border-radius: 15px;*/
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #444;
  display: block;
}
.prev {
  left: 7px;
}
.next {
  right: 7px;
}
.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gallery ul {
  width: 9999px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  transition: margin-left 1000ms;
  font-size: 0;
}
.gallery li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
  <div id="carousel" class="carousel">
<button class="arrow prev"><</button>
<div class="gallery">
  <ul class="images">
    <li class="partn"><img  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3d/Great_dane.jpg/250px-Great_dane.jpg"></li>
    <li class="partn"><img  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3d/Great_dane.jpg/250px-Great_dane.jpg"></li>
    <li class="partn"><img  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3d/Great_dane.jpg/250px-Great_dane.jpg"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button class="arrow next">></button>
<input type="range" value="0" max="3" id="position_new_product" />
  </div>
```

Comment: Эх.. Ну [mcve]...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо хранения числа на сколько элементов надо сдвинуть, можно просто брать его из значения инпута.

Размер сдвига можно определить очень просто: `ширина_изображения*номер_картинки`

`номер_картинки` в данном случае совпадает со значением инпута.

Чтобы список сдвинулся влево - значение у `margin-left` должно быть отрицательным, в итоге функция обработчика изменения вырождается в следующую

```
document.getElementById('position_new_product').addEventListener('input', function() {
  list.style.marginLeft = (-width * this.value) + 'px';
});
```

Рабочий пример:

```js
/* конфигурация */
var width = 256; // ширина изображения

var list = carousel.querySelector('#carousel div.gallery>ul');

document.getElementById('position_new_product').addEventListener('input', function() {
  list.style.marginLeft = (-width * this.value) + 'px';
});
```

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 256px;
}
.carousel img {
  display: block;
}
.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  background: white;
  /*border-radius: 15px;*/
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #444;
  display: block;
}
.prev {
  left: 7px;
}
.next {
  right: 7px;
}
.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gallery ul {
  width: 9999px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  transition: margin-left 1000ms;
  font-size: 0;
}
.gallery li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel" class="carousel">
  <div class="gallery">
    <ul class="images">
      <li class="partn">
        <img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/802d132837bedd698ebd9b8fe7fb77ae?s=256&d=identicon">
      </li>
      <li class="partn">
        <img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=256&d=identicon">
      </li>
      <li class="partn">
        <img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/1ab1d534250b21d145a3bf548b954901?s=256&d=identicon">
      </li>
      <li class="partn">
        <img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ffa137ca41767871222a5ca3d4e24ad?s=256&d=identicon">
      </li>
      <li class="partn">
        <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/905721779505680/picture?type=large">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input type="range" value="0" max="4" id="position_new_product" />
</div>
```

Comment: А для адаптивного дизайна такой вариант разве подходит?

Comment: @Webitek, что вы понимаете под _адаптивным дизайном_ в данном случае, и почему для него может что-то походить или не подходить?

Comment: А где моя аватарка?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, готово :-)

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("#i").on('input', function () {
  $("#dest").css('transform', "translate(-" + $(this).val() + "00%, 0)");
})
```

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  width: 256px;
}

section {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 256px;
  margin: auto;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><input type=range id=i min=0 max=3 value=1 autofocus></p>

<section><div id=dest><img
   src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/802d132837bedd698ebd9b8fe7fb77ae?s=256&d=identicon"
><img
   src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=256&d=identicon"
><img
   src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/1ab1d534250b21d145a3bf548b954901?s=256&d=identicon"
><img
   src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ffa137ca41767871222a5ca3d4e24ad?s=256&d=identicon"
></div></section>
```

Comment: конечно спасибо за код, но можно хоть какое-то объяснение....не все понял. Для чего параметр "e" в функции ?  и что обозначает (-" + $(this).val() + "00%, 0)");  ?  Заранее спасибо и извинения за глупые вопросы для многих

Comment: @Webitek, `e` - это `event` - в данном случае не используется, поэтому можно убрать. Остальное - просто формируется строка как в css `translate(-100%, 0);`.

Comment: @Webitek, лучше бы спросил, [зачем такое форматирование](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468550/178988).

Comment: если поменять событие на `input` - то картинки будут двигаться сразу при изменении ползунка, а не после отпускания :-)

Comment: @Grundy, я просто не был уверен в кроссбраузерности input для типа `range`. Если всё хорошо, то да. Обновил ответ.